# Updating table A with information from table B (which contains duplicate information)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

This is a bit tricky. I've got someone with a very specific request.

This database has two tables: Table A (customer table) and table B (order table).

Table A has a unique customer ID (customerid) for each row. It also has a Date of Service (DATEOFS) column, which is primarily populated with old information from the previous database.

Table B has a unique Order number (ordernum) for each order. Each order is also linked to the customer (customerid) and has the date of the order (dofserv).

To show the Date of Service in the actual PHP script, I use the following query:

```
SELECT dofserv FROM orders WHERE customerid=" . $result['customerid'] . " ORDER BY dofserv DESC LIMIT 1
```

This returns me the most recent date of service for a single customer.

What I'm attempting to do is update the DATEOFS in Table A with the -most recent- DOFSERV from Table B.

As I understand it, the following query would work if there was only one  matching row:

```
UPDATE clients a, orders b SET a.DATEOFS = b.DOFSERV WHERE a.customerid = b.customerid
```

However, since the orders table has multiple rows which match the customerid, I'm not sure how to update the clients.DATEOFS with only the most recent orders.DOFSERV.

Any suggestions? Would like to do this in pure MySQL to run from the command line; I could do it in PHP, but I'm not sure how long it would take to run.

Comment: i am not sure if this work, cause i don't know if in the second select you can use order by and limt: update table a set a.dateofs = ( SELECT dofserv FROM orders WHERE customerid=" . $result['customerid'] . " ORDER BY dofserv DESC LIMIT 1).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is like this:

```
UPDATE clients a
SET
    a.DATEOFS=(SELECT MAX(b.DATEOFS) FROM orders b WHERE a.customerid=b.customerid);
```

But this query will insert `NULL` in `a.DATEOFS` if there is no matching order. If that's not what you want, you can modify it slightly to:

```
UPDATE clients a
    JOIN orders o ON a.customer_id=o.customer_id
SET
    a.DATEOFS=(SELECT MAX(b.DATEOFS) FROM orders b WHERE a.customerid=b.customerid);
```

This query will restrict the updates to only those rows in `clients` where there is at least one matching row in `orders`.

Answer (score 0):

You could `join` the `clients` table on an aggregate query:

```
UPDATE clients a
JOIN   (SELECT   customer_id, MAX(dofserv) AS md
        FROM     orders
        GROUP BY customer_id) b ON a.customerid = b.customerid
SET    a.dateofs = b.md
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way that will only update a minimal number of rows:

```
update clients a
set dofserv = ( select max(dofserv)
                from orders b
                where b.customerid = a.customerid
              )
where exists  ( select *
                from orders b
                where b.customerid = a.customerid
                  and  b.dofserv   > a.dofserve
              )
```